# Python TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Tags: python-3.x, api, pandas, data-science

I am attempting to use an API request to gather weather data and ultimately save the data to a CSV file with pandas.to_csv. The API request is working, but I get this error when I am trying to convert the API response from a dictionary to pandas. Any tips for what I am doing wrong is greatly appreciated:

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

The last line in the code is what is messed up and the shell is returning an error:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
import pandas as pd

api_key = ""
date = "20170601"
zip_code = "53711"

response = urlopen("http://api.wunderground.com/api/%s/history_%s/q/%s.json"     % (api_key, date, zip_code))

json_data = response.read().decode('utf-8', 'replace')

data = json.loads(json_data)

for observation in data['history']['observations']:
     print("Date/Time:    " + observation['date']['pretty'])
     print("Temperature:  " + observation['tempi'])
     print("Humidity:     " + observation['hum'])

df = pd.DataFrame([data], columns=data.keys())
```

The screen shot is what the data looks like in the shell output:
[image]

Comment: Not so easy answering without sample of `json`, but [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) should work.

Comment: How do I get a sample of the json? Is it possible just to to open up a web browser with the correct URL to display the json? Or something in Chrome developer mode???

Comment: There is no `api_key` ?

Comment: where would I stick the `json_normalize` in the code? Thanks

Comment: the API key is a free bee, limit to 50 calls a day I think, do people usually post that stuff? I will if its not a big deal lol

Comment: No, dont do it, because too many people see it... But if really want share it, better is sent it to my email in my profile. But it is up to you.

Comment: Will do thanks, its sent your way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) with filtering columns, also is possible convert date column [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df = json_normalize(data['history']['observations'])

df = df[['date.pretty','tempi','hum']]
df['date.pretty'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date.pretty'])
print (df.head())
          date.pretty tempi hum
0 2017-06-01 00:15:00  49.8  83
1 2017-06-01 00:35:00  50.0  82
2 2017-06-01 00:55:00  49.1  85
3 2017-06-01 01:15:00  49.3  83
4 2017-06-01 01:35:00  48.2  85
```

Comment: I inserted the code above, where I replaced this in my initial code:

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame([data], columns=data.keys())

Comment: but I am getting an error, "NameError: name 'json_normalize' is not defined"

Comment: I add import to answer. I think now it working perfectly.

Comment: Wow thanks a few million on getting this work. Let me know if I need to check any more boxes to state the post was useful. I didnt know I needed to hit the green check box, have a great day!

Comment: Thank you too ;) And nice day also ;)